# Node.js on the same port with apache,proxy pass not working

Tags: php, apache, node.js, virtualhost

So here is my virtual host

NameVirtualHost *:8080

```
<VirtualHost mysite.org:8080>
     ServerAdmin panda@gmail.com
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias www.mysite.org

     ProxyRequests off

     <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
     </Proxy>

     <Location />
           ProxyPass http://mysite.org:8081/
           ProxyPassReverse http://mysite.org:8081/
     </Location>
     DocumentRoot /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/node
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now from my apache app if I try to link a script file like this: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` isn't working I need to do: `<script src="http://mysite.org:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using xhr-polling as the transport, websocket is not likely to work through the apache proxy

```
socketio.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
```

Comment: I think your right, but I'd have thought socketsio would detect this and fallback to long-polling or commet anyway -- Well, I guess that occurs on the browser.